# Running Docker on Mac, build works, run errors: : /bin/sh: 1: [: missing ]

Tags: bash, macos, docker

Running Docker on Mac, I can build my image, but on running, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [: missing ]
```

I create the image in a local directory with 
a dockerfile, requirements.txt and a python script file. - 3 files-
 using docker build

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python
COPY "requirements.txt"
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY "quandlData.py"
CMD [ "python", "./quandlData.py"
```

-simple script that gets some data from quandl API and writes-gets from a redis server- which is running. To run, I just use `docker run image_name`

Comment: Is your container using some ENTRYPOINT or RUN command? Have you tried a different base FROM image?

Comment: I create the image in a local directory with a dockerfile, requirements.txt and a python script file. - 3 files- using docker build 
Dockerfile: 
#!/bin/sh
FROM  python
COPY "requirements.txt" /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY "quandlData.py" /
CMD [ "python", "./quandlData.py"

 simple script that gets some data from quandl API and writes-gets from a redis server- which is running. 
To run, I just use docker run image_name

Comment: Thank you Charles Duffy. That was it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
CMD [ "python", "./quandlData.py"
```

is being parsed as a shell command, not an array -- and the `[` command (when invoked that way, rather than by its alternate name `test`) requires its last argument to be `]`.

In this case, however, adding a trailing `]` will cause your `CMD` to parse as an array describing arguments to pass to `python`, not a `[` command at all -- which it should be.

---

Thus, you can do either of these two things:

```
# BETTER: Fix your JSON array
CMD [ "python", "./quandlData.py" ]
```

...or...

```
# WORSE: Pass a valid shell command
CMD python ./quandlData.py
```